# How to stop a Programmable Voice Bidirectional-Stream from stream capturing app?

Tags: twilio, voice, twilio-twiml

Here is the structure of TwiML for every call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Connect>
    <Stream url="wss://.../stream" />
  </Connect>
  <Dial>
    <Number>999999999</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

But there are some issues we are facing for some features we want to add:

1. Not able to stop BiDirectional-Stream defined by  verb.

There are no message type defined for Programmable Voice Stream to stop a stream, for Bi-Directional Stream. So it's not going to next verb shown above. (ie. )
Here are the docs I am referring: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream

2. Not able to end the call

I am using this code to end the call:

```
async function endCall() {
    // var resp = await twilioClient.calls('CA...').update((error, call) => {
    //     console.log(error);
    //     console.log(call);
    //     call.status = 'completed';
    // });
    // console.log(resp);
    // status='completed'

    const callSid = 'CA...';
    axios.post(`https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${ACCOUNT_SID}/Calls/${callSid}.json`, {
        Status: 'completed'
    }, {
        auth: {
            username: ACCOUNT_SID,
            password: AUTH_TOKEN
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log('Call ended:', response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error ending call:', error);
    });
}
```

But both methods (commented one and non-commented one) are not working for ending a call.

Can you suggest some solutions for both?

Tried different methods and finding something in the docs. But there seems to be no way to achieve these.